# Wild cluster bootstrap in panel data regression in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, economics

I am doing a panel data regression in R. The data set includes several variables for Cantons (swiss jurisdictions) for several years. 
Preparing the data:

```
> install.packages("clusterSEs")
> library(clusterSEs) 
> fakefunk <- plm.data(dataset1, c("canton","year"))
```

I estimate the following fixed effects model:

```
> ffe2 <- plm(logPCexp_r~dummy_bref+sigperpop20_gini_all, model="within", effect="time", data = fakefunk)
```

So far so good. I have few clusters therefore I want to use the wild cluster bootstrap-t procedure following Cameron, Gelbach & Miller (2008). The data is clustered on canton level. I use the following command, yielding the subsequent error message:

```
> cluster.wild.plm(ffe2, fakefunk, cluster="canton", ci.level = 0.95, boot.reps = 1000, report = TRUE, prog.bar = TRUE)
Error in cluster.wild.plm(ffe2, fakefunk, cluster = "canton", ci.level = 0.95,  : 
   invalid clustering variable; see help file
```

My question is simple: What am I doing wrong? The documentation regarding the command is short. Apparently I cannot cluster on "canton". If I choose "group" it does not work either.

*References: A. Colin Cameron & Jonah B. Gelbach & Douglas L. Miller, 2008.
"Bootstrap-Based Improvements for Inference with Clustered Errors," The Review of Economics and Statistics, MIT Press, vol. 90(3), pages 414-427, August.*

Answer (score 0):

Try using: `cluster = ~canton` instead of `cluster = "canton"`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use: cluster = "group"